# Let's get rid of the `administration` tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

There are currently 386 questions with the [administration](/questions/tagged/administration) tag.

It really doesn't provide much value to any of the questions and it's a decent indicator for questions that are off topic, as they're usually about some sort of server administration.

That said, let's remove the [administration](/questions/tagged/administration) tag.

Of course, as when any tag, please remember:

- If the question is about server administration, then vote to close and/or flag for moderator attention.  We'll close the question.  Please remove the tag here.

  - If the question is already closed, please remove the tag.
- If the question remains open and you are removing the tag, please make sure you've fixed up *everything* about the post (spelling, punctuation, grammar, clean up code samples, etc.).

Comment: Fun fact, there are 386 Pokemon in the third generation.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Feel free to catch them all. =)

Comment: I thought the administration tag was for medicine. It showed up on a google search for catheters.

Comment: @LeeLouviere Every time I see a tag like this, it feels like something is being shoved somewhere in me.

Comment: You should go get that checked out. Early detection is vital.